# Uninstall cygwin in windows 7

Tags: cygwin, uninstallation

I will uninstall cygwin in my computer, unfortunately, I have delete all in C:\cygwin directory. For information I use windows 7 as the OS
Is there any way to uninstall cygwin completely?

Comment: You can find solution on Superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/167219/how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-cygwin-from-windows-7